# Issue with Importing Files in NodeJS Application`

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to create a simple API using NodeJS and Express, but am running into issues with importing external javascript code into my application. I have set up the following basic test code:

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var fovea = require('../fovea.js');
var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var port = process.env.PORT || 8000;

var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.json({ message: "Welcome to the Fovea API" });
    var lay = fovea.Layer2D("red", "layer");
    console.log(lay.name);
});
```

The fovea.js file is a js file containing two classes which I have saved in the parent directory. When I send a GET request to the root address, I get the following error being caused by my attempt to construct the Layer2D object:

```
TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'Layer2D'
    at Object.app.post.layer [as handle] (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/server.js:15:18)
    at next_layer (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
    at Route.dispatch (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
    at c (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
    at Function.proto.process_params (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
    at next (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
    at Function.proto.handle (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:234:5)
    at Layer.router (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:23:12)
    at trim_prefix (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)
    at c (/home/daniel/Documents/coding/retina/retina/web/api/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:198:9)
```

Here is the relevant class constructor from the fovea.js file:

```
function Layer2D(name, graphDiv){
    this.name = name;
    this.graphDiv = graphDiv;
    this.traces = [];
    this.hlines = [];
    this.vlines = [];
    this.bounds = [];
    this.visible = true;
};
```

I'm using NodeJS v0.10.25, installed from the Ubuntu 14.04 apt repository.  It seems that the fovea.js file is not being properly imported, but I can't figure out why that would be the case. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How does `fovea.js` look like? The error comes from this file.

Comment: Hi @Pierre-YvesO., see my updated question.

Comment: By the way, the fovea.js file works fine when I run it directly.

Comment: Could you show the whole `fovea.js` file, especially the `export` statement?

Comment: @AlexM Thanks, I didn't know about `export` statements in Node. I have added two, but now I'm getting the error : `TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined.`

Comment: These are the export statements:

    `exports.Layer2D = Layer2D;`
    `exports.Layer3D = Layer3D;`

Layer3D is defined similarly to Layer2D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, the `fovea.js` file should look like:

```
// web/fovea.js
function Layer2D (name, graphDiv) {
   this.name = name;
   // ...
}

exports.Layer2D = Layer2D;
```

As you're defining an object, you need to use the `new` keyword to instantiate a layer:

```
// web/api/server.js

var fovea = require('../fovea.js');

// rest of the code

var lay = new fovea.Layer2D("red", "layer");

console.log(lay.name);
// >> "red"
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you very much.

Comment: It would be even clearer if you do: `var Layer2D = require('../fovea.js').Layer2D` and then `var lay = new Layder2D('..')` :-)